# Why can't I save edits to my vector SmartObject?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm having a weird problem in CS5. I've pasted a lot of eps files into a Photoshop document as smart objects. (The paste was done via drag and drop from Adobe Bridge.) When I edit the smart object, it opens in Illustrator, but when I try to save the changes, I can't get them to update in Photoshop.

If I save the changes and overwrite the original *.eps file, it doesn't work.

If I open the original *.eps file in Illustrator, make changes, and save them, the changes save to that *.eps file, but the smart object must be pointing to a copy, because it doesn't update.

If I save to a new *.ai file, it also doesn't work.

So what do I need to do to edit these vector smart objects *and have the changes propagate back to Photoshop*?

Answer (score 2):

Saving (save as...) to a new .eps or .ai will not work. 
From Photoshop, double click on the smart object layer to open it in Illustrator. *Note: If it doesn't open in Illustrator, it isn't an Illustrator smart object (at least not anymore).* Make your changes and simply save the file (file>save). If the smart object doesn't immediately update in Photoshop, something is wrong with the smart object. Either it has been somehow flattened or rasterized, or something may be wrong with PhotoShop itself. I would recommend restarting your computer and giving it another go. If that doesn't work, you may have to paste a new copy from Illustrator into Photoshop. - Beyond that, I'm afraid it's a tech support issue.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the smart object, save it.
Then, on the original photoshop file go to layer > smart object > update link, select the smart object saved file. You should be able to see the changes